# Pandas : A possible one-liner code that iterates through a list within a cell and extracting combinations from within that list. Using df.apply()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Instead of confusing by explanation, I'll let the code explain what I'm trying to achieve

I'm comparing a combination in one dataframe with another.
The 2 dataframes has the following:

- an address
- the string of the articles from which it was extracted (in a list format)

I WANT TO FIND : address-article combination within one file, say `reg`, that's not present in the other `look`. *The df names refer to the method the addresses were extracted from the articles.*

Note: The address when written 'AZ 08' and '08 AZ' should be treated the same.

```
reg = pd.DataFrame({'Address': {0: 'AZ 08',1: '04 CA',2: '10 FL',3: 'NY 30'}, 
    'Article': {0: '[\'Location AZ 08 here\', \'Went to 08 AZ\']',
                1: '[\'Place 04 CA here\', \'Going to 04 CA\', \'Where is 04 CA\']',
                2: '[\'This is 10 FL \', \'Coming from FL 10\']', 
                3: '[\'Somewhere around NY 30\']'}})
```

[image]

```
look = pd.DataFrame({'Address': {0: 'AZ 08',1: '04 CA',2: 'NY 30' }, 
    'Article': {0: '[\'Location AZ 08 here\']',
                1: '[\'Place 04 CA here\', \'Going to 04 CA\', \'Where is 04 CA\']',
                2: '[\'Somewhere around NY 30\', \'Almost at 30 NY\']'}})
```

[image]

What i did (able to) find is, the records in which there is a mismatch. But unable to get a address - location level info.
My method shown below.

```
def make_set_expanded(string,review):
    rev_l = ast.literal_eval(review)
    s = set(str(string).lower().split())
    s.update(rev_l)
    return s

reg_list_expand = reg.apply(lambda x: make_set_expanded(x['Address'], x['Article']), axis=1).to_list()
look_list_expand = look.apply(lambda x: make_set_expanded(x['Address'], x['Article']), axis=1).to_list()


reg_diff = reg[reg.apply(lambda x: 'Yes' if make_set_expanded(x['Address'], x['Article']) in look_list_expand else 'No', axis=1) == 'No']
look_diff = look[look.apply(lambda x: 'Yes' if make_set_expanded(x['Address'], x['Article']) in reg_list_expand else 'No', axis=1) == 'No']
```

[image]
[image]

The functions, in overall :

- treates an address 'AZ 08' and '08 AZ' as the same
- shows missing addresses.
- shows addresses which came from a diferent article

But instead of showing the whole list as is (i.e including the ones which already has a match), I would like to show only the particular combination thats missing.

For eg in : in `reg_diff`, instead of showing the whole set again, i'd like to see only the address-article combination :
`'AZ 08': 'Went to 08 AZ'` in the row.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, try:

1. convert your "Article" column from string to list
2. `explode` to get each article in a separate row.
3. outer `merge` with `indicator=True` to identify which DataFrame each row comes from
4. filter the merged dataframe to get the required output.

```
reg["Article"] = reg["Article"].str[1:-1].str.split(", ")
reg = reg.explode("Article")

look["Article"] = look["Article"].str[1:-1].str.split(", ")
look = look.explode("Article")

merged = reg.merge(look, how="outer", indicator=True)

reg_diff = merged[merged["_merge"].eq("left_only")].drop("_merge", axis=1)
look_diff = merged[merged["_merge"].eq("right_only")].drop("_merge", axis=1)

>>> reg_diff
  Address              Article
1   AZ 08      'Went to 08 AZ'
5   10 FL     'This is 10 FL '
6   10 FL  'Coming from FL 10'

>>> look_diff
  Address            Article
8   NY 30  'Almost at 30 NY'
```

Comment: Splitting by ', ' is not a good idea i feel. We're dealing with articles, which may contain them.. ```ast.literal_eval``` is a good choice, if we could leverage it.

Comment: Also the case where I mentioned in Note, ```AZ 08``` and ```08 AZ``` should be treated the same

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully sure what your logic is looking to do, so I'll start with some example methods that may be useful:

---

Example of how to use `.apply(eval)` to format the text as lists. And an example of using `.explode()` to make those lists into rows.

```py
def format_df(df):
    df = df.copy()
    df.Article = df.Article.apply(eval)
    df = df.explode("Article")
    return df.reset_index(drop=True)

reg, look = [format_df(x) for x in [reg, look]]
print(reg)
print(look)
```

Output:

```
  Address                 Article
0   AZ 08     Location AZ 08 here
1   AZ 08           Went to 08 AZ
2   04 CA        Place 04 CA here
3   04 CA          Going to 04 CA
4   04 CA          Where is 04 CA
5   10 FL          This is 10 FL
6   10 FL       Coming from FL 10
7   NY 30  Somewhere around NY 30


  Address                 Article
0   AZ 08     Location AZ 08 here
1   04 CA        Place 04 CA here
2   04 CA          Going to 04 CA
3   04 CA          Where is 04 CA
4   NY 30  Somewhere around NY 30
5   NY 30         Almost at 30 NY
```

---

Example of packing rows back into lists:

```
reg = reg.groupby('Address', as_index=False).agg(list)
look = look.groupby('Address', as_index=False).agg(list)
print(reg)
print(look)
```

Output:

```
  Address                                            Article
0   04 CA  [Place 04 CA here, Going to 04 CA, Where is 04...
1   10 FL                [This is 10 FL , Coming from FL 10]
2   AZ 08               [Location AZ 08 here, Went to 08 AZ]
3   NY 30                           [Somewhere around NY 30]


  Address                                            Article
0   04 CA  [Place 04 CA here, Going to 04 CA, Where is 04...
1   AZ 08                              [Location AZ 08 here]
2   NY 30          [Somewhere around NY 30, Almost at 30 NY]
```